# I am getting an exception when i call a Class created by Matlab

Tags: c#, matlab

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;
using Opera;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class FirstWebPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //Inheritance Matlab
    public MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
    public Array result;
    public String str;

    //Page First Loading function
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    //When Log_in Button Clicked
    protected void Login_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Operaclass opera = new Operaclass();

        result = opera.add(3,4);
        str = "" + result;
        result = opera.subtract(5, 4);
        str = str + ":::" + result;
        TextBox1.Text = ""+str;
        //matlab.Execute("questdlg(message, 'Toolbox missing', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes');");

    }
}
}
```

I am getting error at

```
Operaclass opera = new Operaclass();
```

Exception is

> The type initializer for 'Opera.Operaclass' threw an exception.

Operaclass is a class in `Opera` namespace. which is created by `Matlab` as Opera.dll.

Please help..

Thanks

Comment: What is the *inner* exception? Is there any?

Comment: Pardon my technical knowledge. What is mean by inner exception. If it means any wrongly done procedures. I did exactly as instructed here..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYJ7Q4liNYw

Comment: Sometimes, if exception message is not so useful, we got to look at the inner exception by our debugger. Or probably, more easily, where do you get the class from? And do you have link for the instruction?

Comment: Sorry, I check the youtube link, but I do not see any `Operaclass` is used there at all. Do you send the correct link? Please check it again. You can also direct me to the minute and second of the video in case I missed it.

Comment: Thank you so much. learnt a new thing. The inner exception i get is this.. please help {"The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR' threw an exception."}

Comment: OperaClass is created by me. He created matrixexample. I created opera(Operations short name)

Comment: Ow.. :( this may be never ending... and what is the *inner exception* of the *inner exception*? the inner exception you gave is unfortunately not so useful either...

Comment: This exception probably has a inner except again.

Comment: @SunnySabhanam ah, then probably you want to post your `Operaclass` (please click edit and update your question) and check exactly in which line of its constructor it throws the exception.

Comment: This is the next inner exception. {"The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray' threw an exception."}
the next inner exception is
{"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"}
Next inner exception is 
"null"

Comment: Operaclass is generated by MATLAB. What it has is two functions. "Add", "subtract". a+b =c; a-b=c;

Comment: "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" - this is what you need to google. The error message is more useful. Do you use VS2008 as the instructed video?

Comment: no i am using visual studio 2012, matlab R2015a